# Android. How to get instance of fragment using navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation, navigationcontroller

I'm using MVVM and navigation component. Here is my code to navigate to another fragment:

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate((R.id.navigation_photo_detail)
```

But in my PhotoDetailFragment there are also methods that require getting an interface:

```
class PhotoDetailFragment: BaseViewModelFragment() {
// here some code...

fun setPhotoScaleStrategy(photoScaleStrategy: PhotoScaleStrategy) { // this is I need to call when navigate

}

}
```

In order to call these methods I must get a fragment instance. How can this be done using navigation component ?

Please help me.

P.S.  PhotoScaleStrategy is the implementation of strategy pattern. I have several algorithms for image scaling. My fragment needs to receive a concrete implementation of the strategy through an interface. I want it to not know what specific scaling algorithm it uses, but just do the job

Comment: That is not one of the recommended way to [communicate between fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate). Can you explain why you think you need to 'get a fragment instance?'

Comment: @ianhanniballake, because I need to pass PhotoScaleStrategy to my fragment (PhotoScaleStrategy - is interface). Further, this strategy is received by the view model

Comment: Please explain *why* you need to pass an interface to another fragment. What does that interface do? Who implements that interface? Are you passing an interface just because you want to return a result? Show your code - what your interface looks like, etc. Passing an interface is never going to work across configuration changes or process death and recreation - something all of the recommended ways *do* handle for you.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, PhotoScaleStrategy is the implementation of strategy pattern. I have several algorithms for image scaling. My fragment needs to receive a concrete implementation of the strategy through an interface. I want it to not know what specific scaling algorithm it uses, but just do the job.

Comment: Your fragment needs to receive a concrete implementation of the strategy from what other component? Where does that component get the right strategy from? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where I think it would be most helpful to start from the very, very beginning.